# Node logging and error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've created Node js with express and currently I use the console.log to log message and morgan for expresss...for **production** use what is recommended approach to  use for error handling and logging ,there is recommended modules to use? 
Examples will be very useful!

I try with the following

```
module.exports = function () {
    var logger = new winston.Logger({
        levels: {
            info: 1
        },
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.File)({
                level: 'info',
                filename: path.join(process.cwd(), '/logs/log.json'),
            })
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: For production i use https://www.loggly.com/docs/nodejs-logs/ or another external service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) in the past quite effectively. In the below excerpt we are creating a custom log level called info such that we can call `logger.info` to log messages. I believe there are numerous default levels defined on winston which are well documented.

The second part is to define a transport. In winston this is essentially a storage device for your logs. You can define multiple transports in the array including Console logging, File logging, Rotated file logging, etc... These are all well documented [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md). Im my example I have created a file transport where the log file is located under `log/logs.json` within the root of the application. Every time I now call `logger.info('blah blah blah')` I will see a new log entry in the file.

```
var winston = require('winston'),
  , path = require('path')

// Log to file.
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  levels: {
    info: 1
  },

  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      level: 'info',
      filename: path.join(process.cwd(), '/log/logs.json'),
    })
  ]
});

// Write to log.
logger.info("something to log");
```

Comment: Thanks,Can you please elaborate in the answer how it works?2.what is transport & and file name ?

Comment: Thanks voted up!What do you mean by storage ?inside my project like txt file ?

Comment: storage meaning just where the output for your logs will be stored. This could be a file like a .txt (and could be inside your project or anywhere else on the filesystem) or could simply be the console (where there would be no permanent storage of the logs).

Comment: Can you please provide example how to put the file inside my project?which path should I use asssume that Im creating new folder under the root and I call it logs and put there json file which is called logs.json ,thanks in advance!

Comment: I have updated the answer further to use the current working directory (cwd) of the application to save the log file under `log/logs.json`. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks :) last question,if I use it I need to put require it in all my module or just in one place and "somehow" use it in different modules?

Comment: Good question. I never needed to do that myself but it should be simple. If you were to create this logger instance in a new module and use `module.export = logger;` you could then import this module from anywhere in you application and use the same logger instance throughout.

Comment: I see that its working but the problem is that I see just one entry in my json file when the file was called with postman many times ,any idea?

Comment: Sounds like you're overriding the file each time, but I could be wrong. You could try using a WriteStream instead of passing in a filename directly into the transport. Something like `stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), '/log/logs.json'), { flags: 'a' }),`

Comment: I very try to avoid the usage of `process.cwd()`, as you are assuming where the user is when he launched the process. Use something like `path.dirname(require.resolve('../package.json'))` to have the real "root" of your project. You cannot assume the user is in that folder when it executes it.